# Removing detected colorbar in OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I need to remove the color bar that OpenCV creates when you select a point/color, like the one highlighted with the blue arrow in the picture:

[image: app running]

Any tips, please?
Thank you!

Comment: you should state what code caused your problem in the question itself while asking it. this wasn't caused by OpenCV but by some random code "found on the web"

Answer (score 0):

I found out. You just have to remove the lines below from the example found on the web:

```
Mat colorLabel = mat.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);

Mat spectrumLabel = mat.submat(4, 4 + mSpectrum.rows(), 70, 70 + mSpectrum.cols());
mSpectrum.copyTo(spectrumLabel);
```